# ggpy: TypeError: unorderable types: float() > NoneType()

Tags: python, typeerror, python-ggplot

If I write

```
from ggplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ggplot(aes(x='date_hour', y='pageviews'), data=pageviews) + \
    geom_point() +\
    geom_hline(yintercept=[10000])
```

from the documentation http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/geom_hline.html I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/myenv/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ggplot/ggplot.py", line 116, in __repr__
    self.make()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ggplot/ggplot.py", line 636, in make
    layer.plot(ax, facetgroup, self._aes, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ggplot/geoms/geom_hline.py", line 36, in plot
    ax.axhline(y, **params)
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 722, in axhline
    scaley = (yy < ymin) or (yy > ymax)
TypeError: unorderable types: float() > NoneType()
```

My ggplot is installed with anaconda on python 3.5 from conda-forge and it's version is 0.11.5. Installed with https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ggplot

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The following error means that you compare `floats` with `None` values.

```
TypeError: unorderable types: float() > NoneType()
```

Probably the data you passed to `ggplot(...)` contains `None` values.

- Dump the values you are about to plot.
- Remove the `None` values.

#### Understanding the problem:

When the `ggplot(...)` tries to map the points to the rendering area, it makes a comparsion `(yy < ymin) or (yy > ymax)`. It is likely that either `yy`, `ymin` or `ymax` is `None`.